# Como gerar gráficos de médias diárias, mensais e anuais em dados de série temporal no R?

Tags: r, séries-temporais

Gostaria de saber como faço para fazer médias de vários intervalos, mínimas e máximas diárias e mensais de uma série temporal de um arquivo que possui duas colunas (data e o valor da temperatura), porém a data está no seguinte formato yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.

Li algumas perguntas/respostas aqui e fiquei totalmente confusa, desculpem, sou nova no R. Instalei vários programas (xts, zoo, lubridate).

Gerei uma série temporal assim:

```
st <- ts(CEM_1$Temp, start = 2017, frequency = 48)
```

Mas não consigo decompor em médias diárias nem mensais, nem entendi se o arquivo está lendo direito.

```
head(CEM_1)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Data        Temp
  <date>     <dbl>
1 2017-04-18  25.4
2 2017-04-18  24.9
3 2017-04-18  24.8
4 2017-04-18  27.3
5 2017-04-18  26.0
6 2017-04-18  24.8
```

E como fazer os gráficos "para enxergar melhor" esses dados?

Comment: Bem-vinda ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: A pergunta está muito geral, mas antes que feche, `agg <- aggregate(Temp ~ Data, CEM_1, mean, na.rm = TRUE)`. Depois, `library(ggplot2); ggplot(agg, aes(x = Data, y = Temp)) + geom_line()`.

Comment: Perfeito, saiu um gráfico geral das temperaturas todas ao longo do tempo, e agora como fazer médias diárias, mensais, anuais??? Vou colar o script como está ate agora, ok? Obrigada pela ajuda estou tentando entender como a comunidade funciona!!!

Comment: #abrindo arquivo Excel
library(readxl)
> temperatura <- read_excel("PELD/planilhas/CEM_1.xlsx", 
                            +     col_types = c("date", "numeric"))
> View(CEM_1)
> #Abrindo pacote para gerar série temporal!
  library(lubridate)
st <- ts(CEM_1$Temp, start = 2017, frequency = 48)
agg <- aggregate(Temp ~ Data, CEM_1, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
#Depois, 
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(agg, aes(x = Data, y = Temp)) + geom_line()

Comment: Link do gráfico: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JXe1KmHd-QhUYDFLT-JLVUXVkZlP8e2V/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Link da planilha: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lO7z-G-cmUUB6K50AsDLOaf2wyDsjioj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Veja se a resposta está como quer.

Answer (score 0):

Estas duas soluções, uma para as médias diárias e a outra para as médias mensais, são muito parecidas e utilizam o pacote `dplyr`.

```
library(readxl)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

temperatura <- read_excel("CEM_1.xlsx", col_types = c("date", "numeric"))

temperatura %>%
  mutate(Dia = as.Date(Data)) %>%
  group_by(Dia) %>%
  summarise(Temp = mean(Temp, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Dia, y = Temp)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
temperatura %>%
  mutate(Mes = zoo::as.yearmon(Data)) %>%
  group_by(Mes) %>%
  summarise(Temp = mean(Temp, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(Ano = factor(year(Mes)),
         Mes = month(Mes, label = TRUE, abbr = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Mes, y = Temp,
             group = Ano, colour = Ano)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Rui, muito obrigada... estou aprendendo muitoooo...

Comment: mas no final, o gráfico não formou, saiu esse erro:

Comment: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Dia' not found